# Pronoun : Antecedent :: Abbreviation : ___________ ? I.e., is there a name for the corresponding word/phrase to which some abbreviation refers?

Tags: abbreviations

E.g., when you use 'BAL' to refer to 'Baltimore'-- or even the 'Baltimore Orioles'-- we call 'BAL' an abbreviation. What is 'Baltimore' in this context?

I've yet to find support on Wikipedia for my hunch, that this too is an antecedent. It is a logical antecedent, anyway, if not a grammatical one. But the inspiration for this question comes from a real need for the grammatical term, if one exists. (For my purposes, I really hope it does. "There are only two hard problems in computer science...")

Comment: The original form or the full form, depending on whether it's an incomprehensible code fragment (like `MCI` for _Kansas City_) or a mere shortening (like `BAL` for _Baltimore_).

Comment: _full word_ or _full phrase_.

Comment: I suppose you do not want a new word like *abbreviand* ...

Comment: @GEdgar Only if you use abbreviater vs abbreviated, and abbrevign isn't taken.  I am all for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that *expansion* is used [quite often](https://www.google.com/search?q=expansion+of+abbreviation). It is also in the [list of antonyms for *abbreviation*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/abbreviation).

*Full form* or *full meaning* appear to be in use as well, as noted by @JohnLawler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is the 'name.'

It's the name of the city, the name of the team, the name of the system or product.  It seems that the abbreviations are always referring to the 'name.'

Or maybe that is too simplistic...?